# unable to share internet from windows 8.1 and my phone kitkat 4.4.4

Tags: networking, windows-8, android

unable to share internet from pc to phone
before upgrading from red mi 1s version to kitkat I use to connect through usb media

Comment: I don't know how important the usb media is to you, but you can try making a wifi hotspot with your PC if it is capable.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a wifi hotspot by running the following in command line as Administrator:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=enterssid key=enterpassword
```

When you want to start the hotspot, run:

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

To stop the hotspot:

```
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
```

You can also make separate batch files to start/stop your network using notepad, type:
To start:

```
@echo off
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
pause
```

To stop:

```
@echo off
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
pause
```

Save those as .bat files on your desktop and right click run as admin.

Then to share your internet, go to Network and Sharing Center -> Change adapter settings
Right click -> Properties on the connection you want to share internet from, then in sharing tab check the box for "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection"

Answer (score 0):

Stock Kit Kat 4.4.4 does not support that option. Only way to share is to turn Windows machine into hotspot.